# How to default to 0 an empty string http parameter bound from the request to an int property of a form command object using Formatters?

Tags: java, spring, type-conversion

In a spring-mvc application I am binding a string http request parameter to an `int` field in a command object. I set a `DefaultFormattingConversionService` in the `DataBinder`. If that parameter is empty string the bind does not succeed, I get a `typeMismatch` error code for my target field. What I would like to happen in this case is to have a default value (0) set on my int field. I can achieve this by extending the `CustomNumberEditor` class and overriding its `setValue(Object)` and registering it to the `DataBinder` like this:

```
        binder.registerCustomEditor(int.class, 
                new CustomNumberEditor(Integer.class, nfInt, true)
                {
                    public void setValue(Object o)
                    {
                        super.setValue((o == null)? 0 : o);
                    }
                }
        );
```

However, I would like to use `Formatters` to get the same behavior that I get with the above property editor. I like the fact that Formatters can be enabled using field/method level annotations and in general the conversion service framework feels easier to use and configure than the property editors based framework (except for the issue described above).

Comment: If you're using Spring, then you likely use `@RequestParam`, so why not use the built-in options? I.e. `@RequestParam(required=false,defaultValue="0")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am talking about binding an int field that is a member (property) of a form command object.  Your solution would certainly work for a standalone http parameter.

Comment: @Razvan Do you wan to apply this on specific integer fields or on all integer fields in your models?

Comment: @fujy Let's say I need this for all int fields. My final goal is to have this behavior for one specific field. If there is a solution for all I would imagine that maybe I could create my own custom implementation of AnnotationFormatterFactory<Number> then annotate my target field and get the behavior I am looking for  just for that field.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to apply this conversion to all your models' integers, what you can do instead of using `Spring Formatter` is to register a new [`Spring Converter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) where you define your own logic, it can be something like this:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

class StringToInteger implements Converter<String, Integer> {
  public Integer convert(String source) {
    return source != null? Integer.valueOf(source) : 0;
  }
}
```

And you will register in your configuration class like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new StringToInteger());
  }
}
```

You can find more detailed also [here](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-custom-converter/) and [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-using-type-converters-with-spring-mvc/)

Comment: The downside with the Converter instead of a Formatter is that the converter is not Locale aware. My application is localized, so I need access to the locale in any conversion code that I have. I could probably get the locale from the LocaleContextHolder class in a converter, but this feels like a hack. Spring documentation says the following. See next comment.

Comment: In general, use the Converter SPI when you need to implement general-purpose type conversion logic; for example, for converting between a java.util.Date and and java.lang.Long. Use the Formatter SPI when you’re working in a client environment, such as a web application, and need to parse and print localized field values. The ConversionService provides a unified type conversion API for both SPIs.

Comment: @Razvan I thought about converters because you mentioned that you would like a solution that would work for all integers, which converters likely provide. Regarding the locale issue, I don't see it as a problem to set the locale inside the converter, or pass it to the constructor from `WebMvcContext` class

Comment: The locale is only known at request time, each user of the application can set his own locale. So it is not an option to hardcode it in a configuration class.